# How can I center four buttons horizontally and vertically?

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to center four buttons horizontally and vertically. 
Each of the buttons shall get a background image later, so I think it's important that the aspect ratio stays more or less the same, otherwise the pictures won't fit onto the button.

A screenshot of what it should look like: 
[image]

All buttons have the same size and should take up as much space as available (small margin, 10px or so, not more if possible). I don't know how to set the constraints that the application looks good on all devices (iPhone 5s and iPad 10.5"). 

The application must not necessarily run in all orientation modes.

How do I have to set the constraints?

Comment: Put the four buttons in an invisible superview with appropriate constraints and center the superview?

Comment: @matt But what constraints do I have to apply to the superview? Only center X and Y are not enough.

Comment: Correct. You'd want to tie its leading and trailing to the sides of the main view, and then tie its height to its width. Practice by arranging that alone: learn to make a maximum centered square using autolayout. It will then be obvious how to proceed. (In fact, at that point you can just use a UIStackView configuration.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can easily be reduced to the problem of making a maximum square centered in its superview. You can do that easily with just four constraints:

[image]

The rest — the grid of buttons — just falls into your lap. For example, make my blue view a UIStackView containing a two UIStackViews, and there's your grid. Or you could do it with explicit constraints yourself.

If this app can rotate, you might need two sets of constraints, one for when the width is less than the height, the other for when the height is less than the width. You would then have to swap them in code. But that's another issue, and is not difficult.

Comment: Yup, thank you very much, I solved the problem ;-) Works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Add them to UIStackView, for placing them horisontally use **horisontal** value for **axis** property you can customize it with distribution, alignment and other properties of UIStackView.
It's the easiest way